# Eclipse RCP linux unresolved requirement

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

We have a RCP eclipse plugin based UI console developed in Eclipse Release 4.5.1 (Mars.1) with Java 1.8.  We are porting from Windows to Linux x86_64 using Eclipse Release 4.5.2 (Mars.2) with Java 1.8.

When we try to launch the application, the application crashes after display of splash screen with a pop-up saying that a log is created. Please find below a snippet of log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk 2 0 2016-06-06 10:28:58.603
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk [98]
Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme; bundle-version="0.10.0"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64 2 0 2016-06-06 10:28:58.603
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64 [100]
Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.core.net; bundle-version="1.1.0"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 2 0 2016-06-06 10:28:58.603
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 [99]
Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.swt; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64 2 0 2016-06-06 10:28:58.603
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64 [97]
 Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.core.filesystem; bundle-version="[1.3.0,2.0.0)"
```

We're not sure how to proceed as the dates on the plugins show fragments that were created earlier, later, or the same day as the host bundle.

```
Unresolved requirement: org.eclipse.swt_3.104.2.v20160212-1350.jar
Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.104.2.v20160212-1350.jar

Unresolved requirement: org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.300.v20141118-1725.jar
Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20140124-2013.jar

Unresolved requirement: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.0.v20150422-0725.jar
Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk_1.0.1.v20150708-1529.jar

Unresolved requirement: org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.5.0.v20150725-1910.jar
Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64_1.2.200.v20140124-1940
```

Comment: Some of the those versions look wrong. For example `org.eclipse.core.net` is version `1.3.0.v20160418-1534` in Eclipse Mars.2. So it looks like you may not have a consistent target platform. How have you built this RCP? What was your target platform? Your plugins, features or .product file might also have incorrect version requirements.

Comment: We have copied all plugins from the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers into the plugins for Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers. Our target platform is CentOS 7.  The Windows versions of these Eclipse packages also appear to have the same (out of date) version of `org.eclipse.core.net.`  Our target system is not on the internet.  Where can we find the updated versions of these plugins?